# JPA Criteria multiselect without explicit join in SQL

Tags: java, jpa

I have this query in SQL that doesn't use a `join` explicitly:

`select id as parentIds, (select COUNT(*) from ChildTable c where c.matching_id=p.id) as ChildTableRecords from ParentTable p where p.someId = 'some_value;`

I am trying to convert this in JPA Criteria Builder without JOINS. So I tried with joins but not getting results that I get when I run the raw sql:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<ParentEntity> parent= cq.from(ParentEntity.class);
Join<ParentEntity, ChildEntity> childJoin = parent.join("matching_id",
    JoinType.LEFT);
cq.select(cb.tuple(parent, cb.count(childJoin)));
cq.where(cb.equal(some where condition));
cq.groupBy(some group by columns);
List<Tuple> res = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: You didn't create an inner subquery at all and are just selecting a count on a join clause. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Subselect,_querying_all_of_a_to_many_relationship for an example of a subquery being used in the where clause - Unfortunately JPA doesn't support subqueries in the select clause, though some JPA providers (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/OTLCG/queries.htm#OTLCG94376 for EclipseLink ) do. Fortunately, JPA has the size operator to do it for you ("select id, size(p.records) from Parent p where p.someId=:someValue"

Comment: Thanks Chris for the response. Unfortunately, the current requirements require me to use CriteriaBuilder. I used the JPQL approach but it was rejected. I also had an inclination that JPA doesn't allow inner queries that's why I tried with count on left join. I'll keep trying.

Comment: I do use Hibernate as it comes by default in spring-data.

Comment: CriteriaBuilder (api) works the same and supports size the same way - it is just easier to show in JPQL. Only issues is that you need to have a OneToMany there from parent->Child defined so that JPA can determine what to use for the Size operation (which is likely the sub query you wanted to issue anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to achive desired result. Both of them available in Spring Data JPA or Quarkus and every JPA 2.0 compatible frameworks.

#### Example

In the following examples I use two entities in parent-child relation. I also use Quakus and Panache but the only difference just to got an `EntitiyManager` instance.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEMPLATES")
public class Template extends PanacheEntity {

    public String slug;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "template_id")
    public List<TemplateVersion> versions;
}
```

```java
public enum TemplateVersionStatus {
    DRAFT,
    REVIEW,
    ACTIVE,
    REJECTED,
    DEACTIVATED

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEMPLATE_VERSIONS")
public class TemplateVersion extends PanacheEntity {

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public TemplateVersionStatus status;

    @ManyToOne
    public Template template;
}
```

So I have a Tempalte entity (like a parent) and a TemplateVersion (child) each Template can have multiple versions.

#### SubQuery

```java
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(H2DatabaseTestResource.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Transactional
class TupleCountTest {

    @Test
    void subQuery() {
        var em = Template.getEntityManager();
        var criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        var query = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
        var templateRoot = query.from(Template.class);

        var subQuery = query.subquery(Long.class);
        var subRoot = subQuery.from(TemplateVersion.class);
        var countExpression = criteriaBuilder.count(subRoot.get("id"));
        subQuery.select(countExpression);
        subQuery.where(
                criteriaBuilder.equal(templateRoot.get("id"), subRoot.get("template").get("id")),
// optional extra filter
                criteriaBuilder.equal(subRoot.get("status"), DEACTIVATED)
        );

        query.select(criteriaBuilder.tuple(
                templateRoot.get("slug").alias("slug"),
                templateRoot.get("id").alias("templateId"),
                subQuery.alias("versionCount")
        ));
// filter on main query
        query.where(criteriaBuilder.like(templateRoot.get("slug"),"%foo%"));

        var resultList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        resultList.forEach(t -> System.out.printf("Slug is: %-20s with id: %5d -- version count: %5d %n",
                t.get("slug"),
                t.get("templateId", Long.class),
                t.get("versionCount", Long.class)
        ));
    }
}
```

The generated SQL query is

```sql
    select
        template0_.slug as col_0_0_,
        template0_.id as col_1_0_,
        (select
            count(templateve1_.id) 
        from
            TEMPLATE_VERSIONS templateve1_ 
        where
            template0_.id=templateve1_.template_id 
            and templateve1_.STATUS=?) as col_2_0_ 
    from
        TEMPLATES template0_ 
    where
        template0_.slug like ?
```

##### Pros - Cons

- Pro - `@OneToMany` relation on Parent entity is not requred. The sample code contains that relation because the other solution requires. In this case getting versions from template is totally unnecessary.
- Pro - Extra filters are available in subQuery.
- Con - A built-in feature (see below) hardcoded manually.

#### Size

```java
    @Test
    void size() {
        var em = Template.getEntityManager();
        var criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        var query = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();

        var templateRoot = query.from(Template.class);
        var sizeExpression = criteriaBuilder.size(templateRoot.get("versions"));

        query.select(criteriaBuilder.tuple(
                templateRoot.get("slug").alias("slug"),
                templateRoot.get("id").alias("templateId"),
                sizeExpression.alias("versionCount")));

        query.where(criteriaBuilder.like(templateRoot.get("slug"),"%foo%"));

        var resultList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();

        resultList.forEach(t -> System.out.printf("Slug is: %-20s with id: %5d -- version count: %5d %n",
                t.get("slug"),
                t.get("templateId", Long.class),
                t.get("versionCount", Integer.class)
        ));
    }
```

##### Pros - Cons

- Pro - `size` is a standard feature.
- Pro - simplier code, easier to maintain.
- Con - `@OneToMany` relation required on parent entity. In some cases it is not the best way.
- Con? - However size feature designed to count related entities, no extra filters available on count query.

Comment: Thanks zforgo. I haven't tested it but it should be good.